# How to change the background color in repeater control based on the values

Tags: c#, asp.net

Aspx code:

```
<div class="col-3 col-m-12">
    <div class="OrderPageContent" >            
      <h5 style="margin-left:20px">Status :<a style="font-weight:bold;color:green"> 
         <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="YordersButton"  Text='<%#Eval("PaymentStatus") %>' runat="server" CommandName="Button1"></asp:Button></a></h5>
                         
</div>
  </div>
```

Please someone help , i have different type of paymentstatus for ex : Payment not verified, Payment Verified . If my paymentstatus = Payment Not verified i want to make the button background color as red, if Paymentststatus = Payment verified then then button background color as green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something similar to below:

```
<%
if(Eval("PaymentStatus") = "Payment Verified")
{%>

Status :<a style="font-weight:bold;color:green"> 
         <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="YordersButton"  Text='<%#Eval("PaymentStatus") %>' runat="server" CommandName="Button1"></asp:Button></a>

<% } 
else 
{
%>
Status :<a style="font-weight:bold;color:red"> 
         <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="YordersButton"  Text='<%#Eval("PaymentStatus") %>' runat="server" CommandName="Button1"></asp:Button></a>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Getting error : CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

Comment: sorry it should be if(Eval("PaymentStatus") == "Payment Verified")   (two equal signs)